# Defining custom biblatex citation style with all authors displayed

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am trying to define a custom citation style for my text. An MWE is the following

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=none,style=phys, biblabel=brackets,pageranges=false,chaptertitle=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{xxx1.bib}
@article{key1,
  author = {Author, A. and Author, B. and Author, C.},
  title = {paper title},
  journal = {journal name},
  volume = {50}, 
  issue = {4},              
  pages = {15},
  year = {2019}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{xxx1.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citelong}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {
   [%   
   \ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
     \printnames{author},
     \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle},
     \textit{\printfield[citefield]{journaltitle}}
     \textbf{\printfield[citefield]{volume}},
     \iffieldundef{pages}{% NEW
       \printfield{number}%
     }{% NEW
       \printfield{pages}
     }
     (\printfield[citefield]{year})%
   ]%
  } 
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}    
They went to the beach and met with a mermaid \citelong{key1}.    
\printbibliography    
\end{document}
```

The above code produces
[image]
Now, unlike the one above, I want the all of the authors to be displayed not just the first one followed by et al. Biblatex documentation says that printnames should print all of its arguments but it does not in my code. I know that the way I define my custom citation format may not be the best one, that is as far as I can manage on my own by looking at biblatex manual. Therefore I appreciate if your modification does not change the above citation style code too much.

Comment: Do you want all authors shown everywhere, including in your bibliography? Or just in your `\citelong` macro?

Comment: The particular options I have for `biblatex` package already make the bibliography entries to show all authors. For this problem I just want to implement it for `citelong`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `biblatex-phys` style loads `biblatex` with these options:

```
maxnames=999, maxcitenames=2
```

So you just need to override the value of `maxcitenames` when you load `biblatex`. You can just use the `maxnames` option which sets both `maxcitenames` and `maxbibnames`.

```
\usepackage[sorting=none,style=phys, maxnames=999, biblabel=brackets, pageranges=false, chaptertitle=false]{biblatex}
```

To set the number of names directly in your `\citelong` macro, you could use `\printnames[][-\value{listtotal}]{author}`.

I've also tidied up your macro a bit so that punctuation will be more robust.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{citejournaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citelong}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \printnames[][-\value{listtotal}]{author}%
   \newunit
   \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
   \newunit
   \printfield[citejournaltitle]{journaltitle}%
   \setunit*{\addspace}%
   \printfield{volume}%
   \newunit
   \iffieldundef{pages}
     {\printfield{number}}
     {\printfield{pages}}%
   \setunit{\addspace}%
   \printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Although I am still puzzled. Previously I have also tried `\printnames[1-2]{author}`, which, if I understood biblatex manual correctly, should print up to the second author in the list but it still showed the first one only.

Comment: @nougako You can use `\printnames[][-\value{listtotal}]{author}`. It needs both optional arguments for some reason. Actually, your cite command is not very robust. I'll update my question and show you how I would do it.

Comment: You need the empty pair of square brackets, because `\printnames` can have two optional arguments: `\printnames[<format>][<start>-<stop>]{<name list>}`. If only one optional argument is found it is assumed to be `<format>`, so if you want to give `<start>` and `<stop>` you need to put an empty argument in between. This is similar to the two optional arguments of `\cite`.

Comment: @moewe, yeah. should have realized that logic earlier. @David Purton, can you explain why do you have to have `\newunit` in between field elements, e.g. between volume and number?

Comment: @nougako, you shouldn't insert punctuation directly like you have done. (`\newunit` will output a comma and a space.) The advantage of `\newunit` is that it works with `biblatex`'s punctuation tracker and won't give you double punctuation if a field is missing. It allows for punctuation to be moved inside and outside of quote marks automatically based on settings. Have a look at the drivers in `standard.bbx` to learn how to output citations.